# Primefaces datatable rendered

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In Primefaces datatable I want to rendered some row and some row should skip, on the basis of some column value.
e.g

```
<p:dataTable  var="contactVO"   value="#{manageBean.contactDetailList}" ... rendered ="#{contactVO.hiddenContact}>
.
.
.

</p:dataTable>
```

when "#{contactVO.hiddenContact} return true that row should not be displayed.

Comment: You should do that in the model, not in the view.

Comment: Thank you .... This means I need to maintain two list one is original and other one is updated list for the view purpose. when user delete the row we show update the updated (view) list.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, it made sense to me too, I wanted to have a dataTable with conditional row rendereing

This is as close as I got to it... using a panelGrid
Of course you loose all advanced dataTable featues

```
<p:panelGrid id="pg_document" >  

   <f:facet name="header">  
      <p:row>
         <p:column >names</p:column>  
         <p:column >description</p:column>      
      </p:row>
   </f:facet>  

   <c:forEach  items="#{listOfDocuments}" var="document">
      <p:row rendered="#{document.display()}">
         <p:column >
               #{document.name}
         </p:column>  
         <p:column >
              #{document.description}
         </p:column>
      </p:row>
   </c:forEach>

</p:panelGrid>
```